# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get channel with an id or mention, the code itself works but when user gives wrong ID it says: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')

Can anyone help me?

I tried this:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id == args[0]).catch(err => {});
```

And this:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]).catch(err => {});
```

These both things give me error.

Heres the code:

```
if (args[0].startsWith("<#")) channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
        else channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]).catch(err => {
    //do stuff
    })
```

Comment: Well yes, if the id is wrong, then `.find(channel => channel.id == args[0])` returns `null`. Then you try to chain `null.catch()`, of course it can't work

Comment: Yes but how do i fix it? @JeremyThille

Comment: Don't chain `.catch()` or anything else to something that can be null. Sidenote, Typescript would display a warning `.find(...)` can be null

Comment: So i just simply add if(channel == undefined), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so i found out the answer with help of @JeremyThille:
`When the id is wrong it tries to null.catch()

I removed catch from the code and added

```
if(!channel) //do stuff
```

Thanks @JeremyThille

Comment: No need to stringify channel and string compare, just check for `!channel`

Comment: Okay, thanks too

Comment: You can call catch() using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining); which would be ?.catch()

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')` means that you are calling `catch` on `undefined`.

Basically, it's `undefined.catch()`.
Assuming you are working with promises, this can happen when a method that's being called is not present in the object.
e.g

```
const myObj = {
  fun1: async () => {
    const res = await callingExternalFun();
    if (res.error) {
      throw new Error('my error');
    }
  },
};

myObj.fun1().catch((e) => {console.log(e.message)}); // my error
myObj.fun2().catch((e) => {console.log(e.message)}); // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')
```

Here, myObj has async function `fun1` that might return an error. So the `.catch` here comes from [Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

However, `myObj` doesn't have a function `fun2`, it's `undefiend` and `catch` will return this error.